# Argument Out Of Range Exception in DataGridView when Running Procedure / Bulk Insert

Tags: c#, sql, .net, winforms, indexoutofrangeexception

I'm making a program that register an product. This product have several fields, but only two of them are mandatory to start the registration (they can be edited later). Those informations are putted in a `DataGridView`, and then i convert it to a `DataTable`, so i can bulk insert it to a temporary table so i can process and clean all the data in it. Just after the bulk insert, i run a procedure that do all the data treatment and check if the informations are right. In the same procedure, after the checks, i insert the data into the original table.

All this process is ok, everything is running fine in C# and in the SQL Server until it. But there is an error that happens every time when i try to do a `MessageBox.Show()` or when i try to open another form.

Here is the function that i created to run the procedure. Everything is running fine, the only thing that throws the error is the message box. I commented all of them and runned the program again and it didn't throw anything at the end.

Here is the code:

```
public void RodarProcedureAddEdit(string procedureName, bool isAdd)
        {
            string result = String.Empty;

            // Variáveis para definir os parâmetros do frmMessageBox.
            string message = String.Empty;
            string headerText = String.Empty;
            bool isError = false;

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Globals.connectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(procedureName, conn))
                    {
                        comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                        if(isAdd) comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@methodType", "A");
                        else comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@methodType", "E");

                        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID", user.userID);

                        if(isAdd) comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@requestID", 0);
                        else comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@requestID", requestID);

                        comm.Parameters.Add("@responseMessage", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                        comm.Parameters.Add("@responsibleUser", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        result = comm.Parameters["@responseMessage"].Value.ToString();
                        string responsibleUser = comm.Parameters["@responsibleUser"].Value.ToString();

                        if (result == "OK")
                        {
                            if (isAdd)
                            {
                                message = "O cadastro foi concluído com sucesso";
                                headerText = "Cadastro";
                                isError = false;

                                //MessageBox.Show("O cadastro foi concluído com sucesso", "Cadastro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                                this.Close();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // Enviar E-mail quando finalizar a requisição.
                                if (responsibleUser != string.Empty)
                                {
                                    try
                                    {
                                        Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
                                        Outlook.MailItem mailItem = app.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

                                        mailItem.Subject = $"Requisição nº {requestID} foi finalizada - Product Catalog";
                                        mailItem.To = DAO.User.getMailAddress(responsibleUser);
                                        mailItem.Body = Globals.finalizedMailBody.Replace("$requisicao", requestID.ToString());
                                        mailItem.Send();
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception ex)
                                    {
                                        message = ex.Message;
                                        headerText = "Erro";
                                        isError = true;
                                        //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                                    }
                                }

                                message = "A alteração foi realizada com sucesso";
                                headerText = "Alteração";
                                isError = false;
                                //MessageBox.Show("A alteração foi realizada com sucesso!", "Cadastro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                                this.Close();
                            }


                        }

                        message = result;
                        headerText = "Erro";
                        isError = true;
                        //else MessageBox.Show(result, "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    message = ex.Message;
                    headerText = "Erro";
                    isError = true;
                    //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
                finally
                {
                    // Isso foi instanciado para conseguir "criar" uma MessageBox, mais detalhes no formulário.
                    if (message != String.Empty && headerText != String.Empty)
                    {
                        frmMessageBox frmMessageBox = new frmMessageBox(message, headerText, isError);
                        frmMessageBox.ShowDialog();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

At the end, after investigating a lot i find that the error is throwing because of the index in the `DataGridView`.

Here is the complete exception:

```
at System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.PositionEditingControl(Boolean setLocation, Boolean setSize, Boolean setFocus)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.PerformLayoutPrivate(Boolean useRowShortcut, Boolean computeVisibleRows, Boolean invalidInAdjustFillingColumns, Boolean repositionEditingControl)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.ResetUIState(Boolean useRowShortcut, Boolean computeVisibleRows)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.OnCollectionChanged_PreNotification(CollectionChangeAction cca, Int32 rowIndex, Int32 rowCount, DataGridViewRow& dataGridViewRow, Boolean changeIsInsertion)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.OnCollectionChanged(CollectionChangeEventArgs e, Int32 rowIndex, Int32 rowCount)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.AddInternal(Boolean newRow, Object[] values)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.AddNewRow(Boolean createdByEditing)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.set_IsCurrentCellDirtyInternal(Boolean value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(Boolean dirty)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl.OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WmReflectCommand(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SendMessage(Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ReflectMessageInternal(IntPtr hWnd, Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCommand(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr wndProc, IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.DefWndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCommand(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

I tried everything, i even created a new form that was exactly like a message box but it throwed the exception in the `frmMessageBox.ShowDialog();`

I'm using SQL Server as my database.

Can someone help me with it?

Any doubts please feel free to ask! Thanks a lot already!

Edit:

Here is the code of the DataGridView instantiation.

```
            dataMKT = new DataGridView();

            dataMKT.Location = new Point(17, 43);
            dataMKT.Size = new Size(850, 268);

            dataMKT.CellMouseClick += dataGridView_CellMouseClick;
            dataMKT.CellEnter += dataGridView_CellEnter;
            dataMKT.DataSourceChanged += dataMKT_DataSourceChanged;
            dataMKT.DataError += dataMKT_DataError;
            dataMKT.CellValueChanged += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataMKT_CellValueChanged);
            dataMKT.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged += new EventHandler(dataMKT_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged);
            dataMKT.CellEndEdit += dataMKT_CellEndEdit;

            tpgMKT.Controls.Add(dataMKT);
```

And Binding.

`dataMKT.DataSource = Util.Util.GetView(requestID, viewName);`

GetView method:

```
public static DataTable GetView(int requestID, string viewName)
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

            string queryGetTable = $"SELECT * FROM {viewName} WHERE [Request ID] = {requestID}";

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Globals.connectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    using(SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryGetTable, conn))
                    {
                        adapter.Fill(dataTable);
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }

            return dataTable;
        }
```

Comment: Show us the code for the gridview and how you're initializing and binding it please.

Comment: I just edited the post. Thanks!